# WP_Query - Exclude Posts

Tags: wp-query

we have a custom WP_QUERY with these args: https://pastebin.com/drbw0NAG

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_number + 1,
    'paged'          => ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
            'field'            => 'term_id',
            'terms'            => $category_id,
            'include_children' => false
        ],
    ],
];
```

We'd like to exclude those post which are also assigned to a child category.

I mean, we have some terms:

-- Parent 1

-- Parent 2

------ Child 1

-- Parent 3

We'd like to get posts in Parent 2 but **not** those are also assigned to Child 1.

Is it possible? Have you got any suggests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a second tax query for posts not in the child categories of the given category. To do that you'll need to get the IDs of the children. This is possible with `get_term_children()`:

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_number + 1,
    'paged'          => ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
            'field'            => 'term_id',
            'terms'            => $category_id,
            'include_children' => false
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => get_term_children( $category_id, $taxonomy ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ],
    ],
];
```